# How to solve refreshing page in jDateChooser?

Tags: java, page-refresh, jdatechooser

When I select the date from **jDateChooser** it'll **refresh** the whole page.
Because of that the values I give to the text boxes become null and I get null pointer exception.
How can I solve this **refresh** problem?

Comment: could you please show your code more